# node-odbc SSL support

Tags: oracle, ssl, node-odbc

I'm trying to connect to Oracle database from a Linux machine using **node-odbc** node module with SSL configured on Oracle database server. But connection hangs and after some time it returns an error. It seems node-odbc dosen't support SSL encryption.

**Error returned:**

```
{ Error: [unixODBC][DataDirect][ODBC 20101 driver][20101]11603
    at Error (native)
  errors:
   [ { message: '[unixODBC][DataDirect][ODBC 20101 driver][20101]11603',
       state: '21' },
     { message: '[unixODBC][DataDirect][ODBC 20101 driver]7529',
       state: '08001' } ],
  error: '[node-odbc] SQL_ERROR',
  message: '[unixODBC][DataDirect][ODBC 20101 driver][20101]11603',
  state: '21' }
```

Below are the environment details:

**Linux Distribution Name and Version:**

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
Release:        14.04
```

**Driver Manager:**

```
UnixODBC v2.3.4
```

**ODBC Driver:**

```
Name: Progress DataDirect Connect for ODBC Oracle WP Driver
Version: 7.1.6
```

**Connection String:**

```
"DRIVER={Connect64_for_ODBC_71};HOST=<host IP>;PORT=1521;UID=<user ID>;PWD=<user pwd>;
SERVICENAME=orcl;EncryptionMethod=1;Truststore=/root/Oracle_POC/SSL/ssl_certs/server.pem;
TruststorePassword=<truststore pwd>;ValidateServerCertificate=1"
```

**Does node-odbc support SSL encryption?**

Answer (score 0):

The unresolved error codes get returned when the ODBC environment is not configured correctly. The 11603 resolves to "ORA-12203: unable to connect to destination"

Make sure you have incorporated the environment variables from odbc.sh (script installed with the DataDirect Oracle ODBC driver) in the node environment; and try to run it again to load the DataDirect ODBC Driver Manager instead of UnixODBC.